# How to get the corresponding character from keysym code?

Tags: java

I am developing a Java API which is consumed by an angular app. There's a socket which sends all the key events from browser. How can I get the corresponding character of the keysym table?

Something like:

```
int a = 97;
int b = 98;
int c = 99
int enter = 65293;
String character = Keysym.get(a); //outputs a
```

Answer (score 1):

***Solution***

You simply need to cast to `char` :

```
static char getCode(int key) {
    return (char) key;
}
```

***Use as***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getCode(97)); // a
    System.out.println(getCode(98)); // b
    System.out.println(getCode(99)); // c
}
```